# Error Using Java Class in iReport

Tags: java, php, jasper-reports, php-java-bridge

I created a *Java* method and I want to call it from a report, like this:

```
package javafunct;

public class Main {

    public String getTes(){
         return "it work";
    }   
}
```

I want to show that result in my *JR* report, so I put that on a *textField* with expression:

```
new javafunct.Main().getTes()
```

I compiled that, and then I set that jar file to the *iReport* classpath and my *PHP* code.

When I run it from *iReport*, it works, but when I run from *PHP* to open this report, it does not work. The error is:

```
Error evaluating expression :

Source text : new javafunct.Main().getTes()
```

Answer (score 2):

ok,i solved my problem.. i must put javaFunct.jar to folder javaBridge/WEB-INF/lib in my tomcat and then restart tomcat.